# How can I use the make target as a variable in my makefile?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to set up a simple makefile for a project, where I have 10 subproject. Each of the sub projects are in a directory named `1`, `2`, `3` ... `10`. Within each of those directories, I have a single `*.c` file. I have figured out how to compile all of my `*.c` files, but I can't figure out how to use the make target to only compile one particular file. Here's what I have so far:

```
all:
    some code

$(@): $(@).c
    gcc -o $(@)/$(@) $(@)/$(@).c
```

If it helps, this is my general directory structure:

```
├── 1
│   └── 1.c
├── 2
│   └── 2.c
├── 3
│   └── 3.c
└── makefile
```

Comment: You mean you want to build `2/2` by invoking "make 2", or by invoking "make 2/2"?

Comment: I should have made that more clear. I would like to build `2/2` by invoking `make 2`.

Comment: It's bad enough to write a rule whose target is not the name of the thing being built; you're trying to create a rule whose target is the name of *something else that already exists.* It can be done, but I urge you to reconsider the design.

Comment: The problem with `make 2` is that make will interpret this as _re-build the `2` directory if needed_ which is not what you want. Moreover, directories as make targets are a quite special case: make compares the last modification date of the target with that of its pre-requisites to decide whether rebuilding is needed. This is fine with regular files but not with directories which last modification date is **not** the last modification date of their content...

Comment: So the better design would be something along the lines of

    ```all:
        some code
    1: 1.c
        gcc -o 1/1 1/1.c
    2: 2.c
        gcc -o 2/2 2/2.c
    3: 3.c
        gcc -o 3/3 3/3.c```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BINARIES = 1/1 2/2 3/3...

all: $(BINARIES)
    some code

$(BINARIES): %: %.c
    gcc -o $(@) $<
```

Is probably close from what you are looking for. The `$(BINARIES): %: %.c` is a static pattern rule. To understand its behaviour you can read section *4.12 Static Pattern Rules* of the GNU make manual.

Comment: Perfect! Made a couple tweaks and it looks like it was exactly what I needed.